# Using a template in struct plugin

Tags: dokuwiki

The [struct](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:struct) plugin is nice for managing structured data. But so far the only way I found to present the data for one single entry is a simple automatically generated table at the top of the page followed by the content of the entrys wiki text. Since I need the single entry pages to look better, I want to replace the simple table with something more pleasing to the eye like a template page that gets included into the page itself using `{page>_mytemplate}`.

The `mytemplate` wiki page might look like this:

```
==== STRUCTFIELD_TITLE ====

The STRUCTFIELD_NAME is a STRUCTFIELD_CLASSIFICATION consisting
of STRUCTFIELD_INGREDIENTS.
```

"`STRUCTFIELD_*`" should be replaced with the fields defined in the schema of course.

---

The wiki page of the single entry should include the template page as mentioned above with `{page>mytemplate}`.

So my question in essence is: How to include single fields of a schema into a wiki page as template variables, and can this be further automated using one "template wiki page" that gets included via the `{page>...}` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It is discussed in detail here: https://github.com/cosmocode/dokuwiki-plugin-struct/issues/145

In a nutshell: There is a version of the Struct plugin which includes all the functionality needed: https://github.com/iainhallam/dokuwiki-plugin-struct/tree/feature/value